# What does the regular expression /_/g mean?

Tags: javascript, regex

JavaScript:

```
.replace(/_/g," ");
```

I have it in my code but can't remember why or what it does! Can one of you regular expression gurus help?

I know this may seem basic, but regular expressions are not my cup of tea and googling for `/g` didn't help much.

Comment: just to add.. you can use / /gi to make it case-insensitive!
Sometimes you want to change words in a string or a paragraph, but it happens that some of them are in the beginning of a sentence, so they're in most of the cases capitalized, if you use only the g it would replace only let say "Angels" and forgets about "angels" or vice versa, it depends on what you put as arguments.
ps: This works with the replace() method in JavaScript.

Answer (score 188, accepted):

The regex matches the `_` character.

The `g` means [Global](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/global), and causes the `replace` call to replace all matches, not just the first one.

Comment: the hyperlink is obsolete, please include the quoted text next time

Answer (score 37):

Like everyone else has said, it replaces all underscores with spaces. So `"Hello_there."` would become `"Hello there."`

But along with the answer, I want to suggest something to you. Use comments.

In your code say something like:

```
// Replaces all underscores so that blah blah blah blah blah..
var hello = "Hello_there."
    .replace(/_/g, ' ');
```

Answer (score 3):

Returns a new string with all the underscores in the source string replaced with spaces.

Answer (score 3):

we can use the expression `/ /g` to search or extract a pattern more than once, you can use the g flag.