# RegEx only matches last item

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-greedy

I am trying to write my own syntax highlighter in sublime. I think it uses python-based regular expression. Just want to match all tokens in a row like:

description str.bla, str.blub, str.yeah, str.no

My regular expression looks like:

```
regex = "(description) (str\\.[\\w\\d]+)(,\\s*(str\\.[\\w\\d]+))*"
```

Now I expect 1 matches in group 1 ("description"), 1 match in group 2 ("str.bla") and 3 matches in my group no 4 ("str.blub", "str.yeah", "str.no")

but I have only 1 match in my last group ("str.no"). What's going on there?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: `/g` be the thing you're looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6052630/1057429

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have a repeated capture group, (e.g. `(a)*` or `(a)+`, etc), the capture group will contain only the last match.

So, if I have the regex:

```
(123\d)+
```

And the string:

```
123412351236
```

You will find that the capture group will contain only `1236`.

I don't know any way around this (besides hard coding the number of subgroups to capture), but you can try capturing the whole group like so:

```
regex = "(description) (str\\.[\\w\\d]+)((?:,\\s*(?:str\\.[\\w\\d]+))*)"
```

Which should give you

```
['description', 'str.bla', ', str.blub, str.yeah, str.no']
```

Note how the elements are grouped; you have 3 items in the list, the last one being a 'list' within the larger list.

Comment: Thanks, this is a nice workaround. By thy way: ?: (=not capture group) is not implemented in sublime

Comment: @JohnRumpel Hmm, this means you'll be getting multiple captures, some of which won't be relevant. See [how it will be working](http://www.regex101.com/r/bS8tF9).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
regex = "(description) (str\\.[\\w\\d]+)((?:,\\s*(?:str\\.[\\w\\d]+))*)"
```