# Replace only replacing the first

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the following code to allow line breaks in the JQuery UI tooltip function.

```
$(function() {
    $( document ).tooltip();

    $('.linebreak').tooltip({ 
        content: function(callback) { 
            callback($(this).prop('title').replace('|', '<br />')); 
        }
    });
});
```

The problem is that it only replaces the `|` to `<br />` on the first occurrence and then just leaves the | in place for the rest.

Is there a way to replace all of them, not just the first?

Comment: you can try replace(/\|/g, '<br/>')

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To perform a global replacement you can use `g`:

Try this

```
callback($(this).prop('title').replace(/\|/g, '<br />'));
```

More infor is [HERE](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp).

Comment: I will do as soon as it lets me.

Answer (score 2):

```
replace(/\|/g, '<br />')
```

Have a look at this previous SO answer: [What does the regular expression /_/g mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6052616/what-does-the-regular-expression-g-mean)

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/U3VxQ/

Answer (score 1):

use regular expresion
Try this

```
.replace(new RegExp('|', 'g'), '<br/>')
```