# Strange javascript issue when adding 9 digit values

Tags: javascript, addition

I have the following code:

```
    window.total = 0;
    $('.amount').each(function(){       
        if($(this).val()){
        window.total += parseFloat( $.trim($(this).val()).replace(',',''));
        }               
    });
    console.log(window.total);
```

for this example, there is only one input with the class .amount (there can be many), when the user enters a number with 7 digits and 2 decimal points, the above code cuts the number down to 4 digits.

Anything less then 7 digits it works fine. Any ideas why this is happening?

Js Fiddle : [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/dxL6dcob/2/)

Comment: try this: `$.trim($(this).val()).replace(/,/g, '')`

Comment: Works perfectly fine -> **http://jsfiddle.net/wsvkfhzx/** ?

Comment: I added a fiddle, and I'm able to recreate the error . @adeneo, I'm using a library called maskMoney, create the decimal values, so maybe that's what is giving the error.

Comment: That's because you're using a library that adds more than one comma. The solution in the second comment should work

Comment: Thanks all, @SheraliTurdiyev your code solved it. Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, you should use `"xxx,xxx,xxx.xx".replace(/,/g, '');`. It will work [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/sherali/dxL6dcob/8/).

Also, you can see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6052630/4365315